# Explanation needed for this Perl one-liner

Tags: perl

I was trying out a program in Perl to remove duplicate entries. Say

```
File : abc
11
22
11
11
22
33
```

The output should be:

```
11
22
33
```

A Perl [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program) made my job easy. But I couldn't understand it. It's:

```
cat abc | perl -ne '$H{$_}++ or print'
```

With some basic knowledge, I presume that "output of abc is being passed line by line and they are pushing it into a hash... But what does `-ne` stand for? Why have they used `++`? What's the `or` statement? What is the explanation?

Is there a way I could find the number of occurrences also?

```
11 - 3
22 - 2
33 - 1
```

Comment: A oneliner for your last question would be `cat abc | perl -ne '$H{$_}++; END { print "$_ - $H{$_}\n" for sort keys %H; }'`

Comment: Useless use of cat :-) (In both the original example and Stefan's comment)

Comment: That's right, you can just give `abc` as an argument to Perl (after the oneliner), since when presented with an empty STDIN, Perl's default filehandle reads the files specified in `@ARGV` (the argument array).

Answer (score 3):

You are correct so far. This pipes the file `abc` to the `perl` command, which is using a hash. To understand the `-ne` argument, compare it to this code which is pretty much equivalent,

```
while (<>){
    $H{$_}++ or print $_
}
```

To be explicit, I also changed `print` to `print $_`.

Now the reason why this one-liner works is because when incrementing a key's value in the hash by doing `$H{$_}++`, we get a return value of the key's associated value.

The first time we encounter a key (line from `abc`), its value in the hash defaults to `0`. As such, the `or` clause is not yet satisfied and it will continue on to `print $_` (printing the line). But on any subsequent time we encounter a key, its return value will be `>0` so the `or` clause will *short circuit* since any positive integer in Perl evaluates to `true`.

What is interesting to note is that this one-liner will **not work** if we instead write it like this:

```
cat abc | perl -ne '++$H{$_} or print'
```

That's because here we are *pre-incrementing* and the value will be returned *after* we increment it.

Comment: The `or` might be weird if you're coming from languages where control flow is traditionally handled with `if` branches and loops only. There are some other idiomatic Perl statements involving it, for example `open(HANDLE, $filename) or die "cannot read $filename"`. Reading up on these might help you grasp the `or` better. There's also stuff with `and`, most prominently `fork and exit;`.

Answer (score 3):

The command-line option -n loops around your -e code. If you type something like:

```
  $ perl -n -e 'some code' file
```

Then Perl will interpret that as:

```
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
      # your code goes here, each iteration reads 
      # from file and puts into $_ variable
    }
```

file in your example is the pipe output from cat command.

```
$H{$_}++ or print $_;
```

This creates a hash with the lines of your file as keys. If the key doesn't exist, it asigns the 1 value, otherwise post-increments in. The first time ($H{$_}++) is evaluated as false, so Perl executes the or-right sentence. It's the same as:

```
print $_ unless $H{$_}++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Switches `ne` means:

> -e = This command-line switch allows you to run code from the command line,
>       instead of having to write your program to a file and then execute it.
>
> -n = This command-line switch allows you to run a program (usually specified with -e) against every line on standard input.

So this is how line by line output is processed.

Now, for the hash if the new value comes, since its not present is printed, but next time is incremented and the value is not printed due to the or condition.

In order to find the number of ocurences too, i am not sure to do with perl one liner, script will be very easy.

U can also do very simply using sort and uniq in linux:

```
cat abc |sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting example:

```
cat abc | perl -nle'$H{$_}++ ; END { for (keys %H) { print "$_ - $H{$_}" } }'
```